# How Do I Execute btoa(string); using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not exactly sure how I am supposed to execute `btoa(string);` and `atob(string);` without making a large project.
Basically I'm trying to make a Base64 Encoder/Decoder using those two functions, but I can't figure out how to link them to a function in HTML.

```js
function Encode() {
  btoa(string);
}
```

```html
<input id="Encode" type="text" placeholder="Text To Encode/Decode" maxlength="5000">
```

I want to execute the `Encode` function when hitting enter and send the output back into the same textbox.

Comment: Have you tried anything that you're stuck on? This pretty much just consists of one event handler, which reads a value from the input element, runs it through `atob`/`btoa`, and writes it back.

Comment: Try reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has a built in atob and btoa function.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAtob() {
  var val = document.getElementById("inputbox").value;
  var out = document.getElementById("outval");
  out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(atob(val)));
}
</script>


<input id="inputbox" type=textbox />
<button onclick='doAtob()'>Do it!</button>
<span id="outval" />
```